# Changing single variable value in AppController

Tags: cakephp

I have a `Horse` object that has a `completed` variable (text).  I want to be able to click `set complete` in the View and then have that horse's `completed` variable set to "yes."  After this, we would redirect the user to tasks/index.  My thinking is to create `setcomplete($id)` function in Controller, so I could pass `/setcomplete/4` and that horse's flag would change.

I have created a basic view for it, but the idea is that I would not need a view, but I do not know how to get around that....I was thinking of using `$this->render()` or something of this nature.

This is the basic code...pass in the id and then change the variable, then redirect to tasks/index.

I am not getting an error....its just not working, that's all.

```
public function setcomplete($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Task->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid task'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $this->set('completed', 'yes');
            if ($this->Task->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {

        }

    }
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?  However `$this->layout = $this->autoRender = false;`, will stop it from throwing errors about a missing view.

Comment: im seeing no behavior at all...i set up a very basic view and it goes there but it doesnt change the variable, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: Can you add `debug($this->request->data)` above the line that does the save and post the results here? Might help pinpoint the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of your problem. you want to set the `completed` to `yes` for `Task` model. 
i think you've done in a wrong way here.

```
what about the $this->request->data here?
```

Does it contain the data you want to save for the task model like the structure as below

```
Array(
    'Task' => Array(
        'id' => 4, // for eg..
        'completed' => 'yes'
    )
)
```

if not

you can solve the problem by doing like this. [Assuming you don't have `$this->request->data`]

```
public function setcomplete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Task->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid task'));
    }

    $this->Task->id = $id;
    $this->Task->set('completed', 'yes')

    if ($this->Task->save()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task has been updated.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```